# How to remove random margin?

Tags: html, css

I wanted to make a box for my website.

When I made it, some text moved down. Then I checked in Chrome dev tools and saw the box had a margin. I do not want that margin!

If I'm making any sense to you, please help!

```css
#route{
     height:300px;
     width: 300px;
     border: 1px solid black;
     padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="route"></div>
```

Comment: Not enough info to help you. The only thing for sure - if it helps - something causes margin. Maybe it's collapsing margins.

Comment: You need to give us more of your html. All would be helpful.

Comment: There are no random margins ..

Answer (score 0):

If there is a margin, then it may be inherited from a parent element. You should be able to pinpoint what CSS is causing this, by toggling the active CSS items within the developer tools you used to inspect the element. You may want to check out https://developer.chrome.com/devtools for more info since you haven't supplied enough code here for anyone to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share more on this ?

What random margin do you get?...from my suspicion its that you are getting something like this

[Browser window with margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psRNO.png)

i.e. Your borders do completely touch the edges of your browser and when you inspect elements you get a body with an extra margin.

```
body {
display: block;
margin: 8px;
}
```

Most browsers do set a margin on the body element and you can easily remove this by using the code fragment below

```
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0
}
```